# How to get "Sent Message" from Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

For Google Apps Script, how do you read Sent Messages?

I don't see anything specifically for Sent Messages under GMailApp, and I don't think "Sent" is a label that I can use with `getUserLabelByName()`.

Comment: Do you think the getInbox function queries the Sent folder?

Comment: `SENT` is a label. :)

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you Tholle!

Comment: "[Imap]/Sent"...too funny!

Comment: I was wrong...the best I can figure is utilize the search....Does anyone know how search GMail Labels?

Comment: var threads = GmailApp.search("is:sent", 0, 500);

Comment: You could add it as an answer to the question below :)

Comment: thank you Tholle...invaluable as ever!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting unread count in Sent Folder using Google Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367410/getting-unread-count-in-sent-folder-using-google-apps)

Answer (score 5):

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("in:sent", 0, 500);
```

Comment: `is:sent` is not included as a Gmail search operator on [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: Should use `in:sent`